# Tmux if-shell slows down on one of my computer

Tags: tmux

I have the following configuration in my .tmux.conf file

```
is_vim='echo "#{pane_current_command}" | grep -iqE "(^|\/)g?(view|n?vim?)(diff)?$"'
bind -n C-h if-shell "$is_vim" "send-keys C-h" "select-pane -L"
bind -n C-j if-shell "$is_vim" "send-keys C-j" "select-pane -D"
bind -n C-k if-shell "$is_vim" "send-keys C-k" "select-pane -U"
bind -n C-l if-shell "$is_vim" "send-keys C-l" "select-pane -R"
```

So that I can switch between shell and vim panes in tmux.

The problem is that when I hit 'C-h', it take a while(~1s) to switch to another pane. It does not matter which pane was the original and which pane was I jump to.

If I change the configuration to the following, the pane switch would work without delay.

```
bind -n C-h select-pane -L
bind -n C-j select-pane -D
bind -n C-k select-pane -U
bind -n C-l select-pane -R
```

Even I do not call a shell function like the following, the switching is still slow.

```
bind -n C-h if-shell "" "send-keys C-h" "select-pane -L"
bind -n C-j if-shell "" "send-keys C-j" "select-pane -D"
bind -n C-k if-shell "" "send-keys C-k" "select-pane -U"
bind -n C-l if-shell "" "send-keys C-l" "select-pane -R"
```

The strange part is that this problem only happen on my work computer, not on my own computer. I think this maybe related to security features on my work computer. But I do not know how to debug this issue.

Could someone help with this? Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you set `set -s escape-time 0` in your tmux.conf?

Comment: I already have it.

Comment: It will be difficult but you can try starting your tmux with `strace -f -r -o log tmux ...` You will get a huge log with all the system calls of all the child programs, with relative timestamps. Try reducing your startup and what you do to a minimum to see if you can easily spot a 1 second wait.